# Decomposition of infinite nuclear $C^*$ algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras

Every finite dimensional $C^*$ algebra can be decomposed into the finite direct sum of the form $M_n(\mathbb{C})$.I guess that every infinite nuclear  $C^*$ algebra can be decomposed into $c_0$ sum of  the form $M_n(\mathbb{C})$.Is that true?If it is true,how to prove it?

Comment: Well, not exactly. I think the correct genralization of $M_k(\mathbb{C})$ in that context is a simple $C^\ast$-algebra, ie a $C^\ast$ without closed ideals. But even using that notion, you would not get a $c_0$ sum in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. Even Abelian $C^\ast$-algebras fail that if their spectrum is not discrete.